# How to set fps for extracting frames from a video?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a video around `30` fps. I want set fps rate to `70` manually with `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, int(fps_num))`. But it always gives `False` as an output. How can I fix this issue?

```
import cv2
fps_num = 70

file = "./test.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, int(fps_num))
```

> output: False

Comment: it doesn't work like that. you can't just change the frame rate of a **video file**. -- you can read it as quickly as the computer is able to, regardless of its stated frame rate. that value doesn't affect you.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from the stream. You can get the FPS rate of the original video. If you want to set the FPS rate, that means you want to write an output stream. See [`cv::VideoWriter`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html).